# laravel 5.2 session id keeps on changing

Tags: laravel

I am trying to access to a stored `Session ID` and use it as a reference.

In `laravel`, the `session ID` keeps changing in every request. I understand this has been done to avoid `session hijacking`.

One possible solution is to use `Session::unguard()`, but how to use this?

*The above code does not help, because the `session ID` keeps on changing:*

```
     $ses = session()->getId();
     $a =session()->getId();    
     $chat = chatParticipants::where("session_id", $a)->first();
```

Comment: Why don't you generate some unique value yourself and store/retrieve that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. You can regenerate the ID manually as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data):

   `$request->session()->regenerate();`
2. Storing a key with every session, and use it for reference.

To store a new key:

```
`session(['key' => 'value']);`
```

To retrieve the key:

```
$value = $request->session()->pull('key', 'default');
```